# Webscraping Youtube pages

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, youtube

I'm trying to web scrape a youtube channel name via a link. But I get the error code:

```
title = response.find_all('div', class_= "style-scope ytd-channel-name")
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

Link to site: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCHOgE8XeaCjlgvH0t01fVZg

Code:

```
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCHOgE8XeaCjlgvH0t01fVZg'
response = requests.get(url)

title = response.find_all('div', class_= "style-scope ytd-channel-name")
soup = BeautifulSoup(title.text, 'lxml')
print(soup)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you know what the error means?

Comment: no, I thought at first it meant that it couldn't find any element with the class. But testing out other people codes I get the same error with the attribute

Comment: It means that the method doesn't exist for the object that you're calling it from. The variable response doesn't have the method find_all, which is causing an error when called.

Comment: hmm alright. But what is the fix then? I thought that BeautifulSoup was able to find all elements with a certain class

Comment: If the answer has been helpful, please upvote and/or mark as the answer please. If not, I'm happy to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use this.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs # importing BeautifulSoup


video_url = "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCHOgE8XeaCjlgvH0t01fVZg"
# init an HTML Session
session = HTMLSession()
# get the html content
response = session.get(video_url)
# execute Java-script
response.html.render(sleep=1)
# create bs object to parse HTML
soup = bs(response.html.html, "html.parser")
name = soup.find('yt-formatted-string', class_='style-scope ytd-channel-name')
print(name.text)
```

Output:-

```
TheTekkitRealm
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code returns the divs:

```
url = "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCHOgE8XeaCjlgvH0t01fVZg"
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "html.parser")
print(soup.div)
```

The value being returned can be changed through the 'soup.' value (e.g. soup.title).

I link to the documentation because I think it would be useful for you to look at too:
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. More like an advice. In my view.

Comment: Also, this won't work. Most of the YT data is rendered by js..BeautifulSoup will not work.